# django rest framework accept post request from Postman not from Android virtual device flutter

Tags: django, flutter, bad-request

```
Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = {
      "brand": brand,
      "quantity": t_quantity,
      "transaction_type": selectedChoice,
      "almari": almari,
      "emp_id": emp_id,
      "emp_name": emp_name,
      "user_name": it_support,
      "opr_name": "flutter admin",
      "asset_name": pk,
    };

    String jsonString = jsonEncode(jsonData);

    var a_response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('http://10.10.148.148:8000/api/transaction/'),
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: jsonString);
    if (a_response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('POST request successful');
    } else {
      print('Request failed with status: ${a_response.statusCode}');
    }
```

> Bad Request: /api/transaction/
>
> [10/Jul/2023 13:36:27] "POST /api/transaction/ HTTP/1.1" 400 58